# Django runserver under Jenkins does not work

Tags: python, django, jenkins

I have created a script to build my Django project which is called by my Jenkins CI, every time a push is made.

The script runs just fine if I run it manually, but fails to start the web server when it is ran automatically.

No errors are thrown, but the last line of the script:

```
nohup python manage.py runserver 0:9000 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

has absolutely no effect.

I am 100% sure that the script is ran as jenkins user, under my virtualenv, so that's not the problem. Also, permissions are not a problem, I have checked. Like I said, no error is thrown, so I don't really know what is happening.

Any ideas ?

Comment: So this line is in an execute shell of your job config? Pretty sure Jenkins sometimes has trouble running processes like serving applications in the background. Check this out and see if it helps https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, thanks to [tomrom95](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5085539/tomrom95) I found the solution : adding `BUILD_ID=dontKillMe` in front of the command fixed everything. It's kind of funny.

[Here is the link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller#ProcessTreeKiller-Ifyourbuildwantstoleaveadaemonrunningbehind...) to a more complete answer to why this didn't work and why it works now.